# Add router-link-exact-active to parent component when child component is in view

Tags: vue.js

I have character component where I have a listing of characters. Each characters have a router-link which is redirecting to characters detail component. I want to add router-link-exact-active in Nvabra's character when character detail is in view.

```
{
    path: '/characters',
    name: 'characterList',
    component: () => import('../components/characters/characterList.vue')
  },
  {
    path: '/characters/:id',
    name: 'characterDetail',
    component: () => import('../components/characters/charactersDetail.vue')
  },
```

Navbar

```
<ul class="navbar-nav m-auto custom-nav">
  <li class="nav-item">
   <router-link to="/">home</router-link>
  </li>
  <li class="nav-item">
   <router-link to="/about-Us">about us</router-link>
  </li>
  <li class="nav-item">
   <router-link to="/characters">characters</router-link>
  </li>
  <li class="nav-item">
   <router-link to="/our-comics">comics</router-link>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Try something like this `<li :class="{'router-link-exact-active': $route.name === 'characterDetail'}">`

Comment: Thnx, it worked...